# how do i make a call to a function with an Int list parameter in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, function-call

I have a function signature like this:

```
def countChange(money: Int, coins: List[Int]): Int = {
```

and need to make a call to the function with parameters such as this: money = 4, coins = [1,2]

?

Comment: I tried a lot of different things but not that for some reason. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies right on the surface:

```
countChange(4, List(1,2))
```

Don't take it as an offence, but perhaps you should read [some basic tutorial on Scala](http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/basics.html)?

Comment: thankyou, I have been reading a couple my instructor gave me and a few things on google.